# Run local jar file using Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jar

I created a bot in Java to access a website and download some informations for me. This jar file is stored in my Desktop.

Now I want to schedule a job in Jenkins to run this bot everytime I want.

When I run my jar file in cmd, everything is fine, but when I do it in Jenkins I get no results (website doesnt't open).

In Jenkins I'm creating a new free-style project and adding the following code into Build:

```
cd C:\Users\gabriel.galvao\Documents
java -jar automatic.jar
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share details on how you are trying to run the jar in jenkins for help others point out any folly in your approach.

Comment: Why Jenkins? Instead of using it, why dont you create a schedule in your own Java code, using threads?

Comment: @fernandokarpinski Because I have other routines running, I want them to be all sincronized.

Comment: @SaurabhMishra Done, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Jenkins won't be able to deploy a .jar file. You will either have to make it a .war/.ear, or you may have to use other application server. Probably your .jar file will be a fat .jar file, and that's why it was running with `cmd`.